# VBA - ShowModal = False does not open UF

Tags: excel, vba

In my Workbook I have an UserForm. While the UF is open I want that it is possible to make some changes in the worksheet or in another workbook.

I tried it with:

```
Call UserForm1.Show(vbModeless)
```

and:

```
UserForm1.Show vbModeless
```

Also I change the UF Settings by "ShowModal" to False.

But with all three examples the UF is shown and closed in a few seconds. So I can not fill the TextBoxes in the UF. The Makro runs without stopping when UF is shown

What do I have to change, that my macro will stop after it reached `UserForm1.Show vbModeless` ?

Whole Macro:

```
Sub Test_Click()
    Call UserForm1.Show(vbModeless)                  ' First Try
    ' UserForm1.Show vbModeless                      ' Second Try
    ' Change UF Settings ShowModal to False

    If UserForm1.ActiveControl.Name = "Cancel" Then
        Unload UserForm1
        Exit Sub
    Else
        ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("WWP")).Visible = True
        ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("WP")).Visible = False
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Modeless form that still pauses code execution](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16859038/11683)

Comment: Your question suggests that you want execution to stop once the form is shown, i.e. not continue down the `Sub` and process the later commands. I'd suggest you remove the code *below* the `Userform1.Show` and put that code in another routine that gets called when you want it, not immediately after the form is displayed.